# Exporting DWG from ArcMap need to unify segments to polylines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, cad, dwg, editing

I am attempting to export to CAD a contour shapefile I have derived from LIDAR imagery.

Once exported I bring the contour DWG into ArchiCAD, drag ' drop, boom it opens, except:

Any curves are broken down into thousands of single small co-joined lines, and unlike Autocad, I don't have an effective-efficient way to polyline edit, make continuous sections into single polylines or splines as they'd be referred to in ArchiCAD.

Is there a way to set up my shapefile, edit or geoprocess it prior to export?

Comment: Did the contour shapefile have those fragment lines already? How did you create it? Can you share a sample file and show some illustrations (before and after?)?